# jQuery fullCalender is not loading properly in SharePoint Online

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, sharepoint-online

I am working on sharePoint Onlie with Content Editor webparts. I have a JQuery [fullCalender](https://fullcalendar.io/) on the page. The problem i am having is: When I initially load the startpage with the calender on it, it works perfectly. but if I go to a diffrent page on sharepoint and then return to the calender startpage with fullCalender I get this message sometimes `VM27768 Startsida.aspx:1145 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).fullCalendar is not a function` My guess is that the fullcalender code runs before the `fullCalnder.js` script is loaded. I checked the network tab and the fullCalender script gets loaded. Any ides where my code is faulty?  Here is my code:

```
<script src="/sites/web/modules/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/web/modules/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script>
    (function() {

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(upSpIsLoaded, 'sp.core.js');
        });

        function upSpIsLoaded() {

            AjaxCallToSharePoint(); //<--fullCalender gets called here when the AJAX completes.
        }


        function RenderFullCalender(array) {
            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({}); < --The code stops here--
        }




function AjaxCallToSharePoint() {
        var DateRAngeFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDT00';

        var ThreeMonthsEarlier = moment().add(-3, 'months').format(DateRAngeFormat),
            ThreeMonthsFromNow = moment().add(3, 'months').format(DateRAngeFormat);


        var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Program')/items?
                    $select=Bokning_x0020_fr_x00e5_n%2CBokning_x0020_till%2CTitle%2CMax_x0020_antal_x0020_platser%2CKontaktperson&$filter=Bokning_x0020_fr_x00e5_n%20ge%20datetime'${ThreeMonthsEarlier}%3A00%3A00'%20and%20Bokning_x0020_fr_x00e5_n%20le%20datetime'${ThreeMonthsFromNow}%3A00%3A00'`;

        //Making Call
        var call = jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });

        //Done
        call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //Filling globalArray
            window._cache.globalArray = data.d.results;

            //Drawing Calender
            RenderCalender(window._cache.globalArray);
            RenderDatePicker();
        });

        //Fail
        call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        });
    }

    });



    <script >
```

Comment: open the developer tools on your web-page and type (into JS console) `jQuery.fullCalendar({})` to see if it is actually loaded

Comment: Since we don't know what `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` or `AjaxCallToSharePoint` actually do, then it's impossible to be certain this is correct. But certainly waiting until document.ready before you render the calendar should work. You can always check via your browser's network tab that fullCalendar.js did actually load correctly. BTW you forgot to include momentJS by the looks of it

Comment: @zeropublix When i type in `   jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({}); ` in the console after I get the error I get the following response: `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).fullCalendar is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:24`

Comment: @ADyson `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded ` is a function Microsoft has written that waits for the sp.core.js to load. Do you want me to post the `AjaxCallToSharePoint ` function?. Its a ajax call that calls the `RenderFullCalender` in the done section with the retrived data.

Comment: @AllramEst that means the script is probably not loaded correctly.

Comment: To help the best way possibe, what would you liek to see from my code?

Comment: "Do you want me to post the AjaxCallToSharePoint function?" There's no harm in doing so, it would help to clarify, I think. Also did you do as I suggested and check whether the fullcalendar.js file is loading properly at the times when this error occurs?

Comment: Updated the question. And looked at the network tab. the error aoccurs when the `fullCalender.js` is being loaded from the disk.

Comment: "the error occurs when fullCalendar.js is being loaded from the disk". What error is that? You mean that fullCalendar.js fails to load? e.g. you get a 404 (or other non-200 response) for that file in the Network tab? It's not totally clear what you mean.

Comment: I get status `200` when loading from the disk or memory.

Comment: are you loading moment.js before fullcalendar.js ? There is a dependency on moment as well. You first need to load jquery, then moment and then fullcalendar

Comment: I solved it. There was a conflict wit SharePoint responsive.UI and fullCalender. We removed SharePoint responsive.UI  and it started working properly.